# microsoftgraph oauth2 scope

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to read/write events from office365 calendar using microsoftgraph api.  I cant seem to get the correct scope, I only get user.read when I need calendar.readwrite.  here is my code request, I have tried adding scope and I have calendar.readwrite defined in the permissions in the registration portal but always I only get user.read. when I get an access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={CLIENT_ID}&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https://localhost&
state=985542
```

how do I increase the scope of my application?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your application is in a state where you have consent for the `user.read` scope, but not the `calendar.readwrite` scope.

Specifically, my guess is that you registered your app with only the `user.read` scope, and then consented to the app. This worked, and your tokens started getting the `user.read` scope. Then at a later time, you added the additional permission for `calendar.readwrite`, however you do not see it in the token!

That is because you have not **re-consented** to the application, with the new scope. If you change the permission levels of your application, you must also re-consent to the new application. If you do not, you will continue to get the permissions that you have consented to in the past, regardless of what they were.

To fix this, simply add `&prompt=consent` at the end of your login url, which will force the user to consent to the new set of permissions.

This happens because our token service first checks if there are EntitlementGrants written between the user and the application. If there are, they will skip all the consent processes, and just jump to minting the token. If you were to delete the consent record, or force the user to consent again, we will start the process from scratch, which will result in all the permissions you have selected.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I tried adding prompt=consent to the end of my login url and it says "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in  we received a bad request' but without prompt tag it gives me a code

Comment: I started over and created a new app registration and now I'm getting the calendar.readwrite so that worked.

Comment: If you would like to debug the error feel free to copy your login URL here. Otherwise, I am glad you were able to resolve your issue.

Comment: One more question, Can I use this same access token to get data from the EWS interface?  I have another app using EWS but with basic auth and I would prefer using OAuth2

Comment: Every access token has one "resource" for which it is defined access for. Using this access token, you would not be able to call another API at a different endpoint. You must either exchange the token for one with the correct endpoint, or re-authenticate with the correct resource defined in the flow. Note here that MS Graph (microsoft.graph.com) and Exchange WS (outlook.microsoft.com) are different resources, and require different tokens.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, is it possible to do account impersonation with MS Graph?